# Join string from list of string on range of index

Tags: c#, linq

I have a big list of string, and i need another list of string which contains string.join by comma of first 300 indexes after that another 300 and so on.. until all string is completed.
Here i'm showing what i have done.

```
    List<string> tempSMSNoList = SMSNos.Split(',').ToList(); // 938
       if (tempSMSNoList.Count > 300)
        {
           int Quotient = tempSMSNoList.Count / 300;   // 3
           int Remainder = tempSMSNoList.Count % 300;  // 38

           List<string> myNewString = new List<string>(); // Need to store new value in this list.
           for(int i=0; i < Quotient; i++)
           {
             // Logic here..
           }
        }
```

Comment: So what to do with 3 and 38 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code should not compile, due that `Quotient` is an `int` type and not a class contain `Count` property.

Second, There is a Linq `Skip` and `Take` methods that can help make a new collection of values.

```
int groupSize = 300;
var numberOfGroups = Quotient + (Remainder > 0 ? 1 : 0); // If there is any remainder then add it as another loop.
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++)
{
    List<string> myNewString = tempSMSNoList.Skip(i*groupSize).Take(groupSize).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  sir, for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ for that

```
var result = new List<string>();
int groupsize = 300;
for (int i = 0; i< tempSMSNoList.Count(); i+= groupsize)
    result.Add(String.Join(",", tempSMSNoList.Skip(i).Take(groupsize));
```

Comment: Your answer is also solving my problem.